# Can't figure out how to change font color, using jQuery (trying to build a simple menu)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just can't figure out how to change the color of the active button pressed to "color:white;"... Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLXBR/

Sorry for the mess (?) in the file, my css is at the button of the CSS box (Foundation code first).

If you look at the jsfiddle, if you press a button that has a sub menu, if becomes green. I want the text in the green box to become white while it's active just like it becomes green. I've tried everything (expect the right solution I guess)... Any ideas?

**EDIT: Sorry didn't know you had to include code...**

CSS:

```
/* Menu styling */

.side-nav {
    padding: 0px;
}

.side-nav > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
    margin: 0px;
}

.side-nav > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #181818;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.side-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #eaeaea;
}

.is-sub {
    background: #2d2d2d;
    margin: 0px;
    display: none;
}

.is-sub > li {
    background: #2d2d2d;
    margin: 0px;
}

.is-sub > li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #a7a7a7;
}

.has-sub.active {
    background: #48AC40;
}
```

Javascript

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.has-sub').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).children('.is-sub').slideToggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="side-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#" class="">Posts</a>
                <ul class="is-sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Add a new Post</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Edit Posts</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#" class="main">Manage</a>
                <ul class="is-sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Categories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Users</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Define style for `.has_sub .active` or inside callback function `if ($this).hasClass("active") { $(this).css("color", "white"); } else { $(this).css("color", "inherit"); }`

Comment: And another one who ignored the message that jsfiddle links have to be accompanied with code. Instead we have a tinyurl. Show some code.

Comment: Include relevant code!

Comment: Microbe: .has-sub.active { background: #48AC40; } exists in the css but adding: color:white; does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.has-sub').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).children('.is-sub').slideToggle('slow');

        if ( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
            $("a", this).eq(0).css("color", "white");
        } else {
            $("a", this).eq(0).css("color", "");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding color:white to the .has-sub.active { background: #48AC40;} does not do anything unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated my answer. White color must set to `<a>` tag instead of `<li>`. The problem still exists is on hover color not changes.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm! I still do not really understand why it works. I'm new to JQuery so. Is it possible to do the same thing but in the CSS code, I'm sure I would understand that solution better! Thanks yet again!

Comment: I make my last update, the color definition must be empty string in case if class `active` not exists

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this way:

```
$('.has-sub').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).children('.is-sub').slideToggle('slow');

    if ( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
        $(this).find('a').css("color", "#ff0000");
    } else {
        $(this).find('a').css("color", "#eaeaea");
    }
    return false;
});
```